# MVC 3 Model Properties Without Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to include a property in a model that is not bound to the database?  For instance:

```
Public Class Tbl_Forum_Topic

    <Key()> Public Property FTopic_ID() As Integer
    <ForeignKey("Tbl_Forum")> _
    Public Property FTopic_Forum_ID() As Integer
    Public Property FTopic_Employee_ID() As Integer
    Public Property FTopic_Resource_ID() As Integer
    Public Property FTopic_Title() As String
    Public Property FTopic_Content() As String
    Public Property FTopic_Create_Date() As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property FTopic__Deleted() As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Public Property FTopic_Deleted_Date() As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property FTopic_Status() As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Public Property FTopic_Publish() As Nullable(Of Boolean)

    Public Overridable Property Tbl_Forum() As Tbl_Forum

    Public Overridable Property Tbl_Forum_Replies() As ICollection(Of Tbl_Forum_Reply)

    Public Overridable Property Last_Reply_User_Name() As String

End Class
```

The last item is called `Last_Reply_User_Name()`.  It is not in my database, but I want to loop through and perform a calculation in my controller action to set it based on values from other database tables.  I get an error `Invalid column name 'Last_Reply_User_Name'.` when I try this code.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that you're actually asking about Entity Framework.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 (as tagged).  I am not using Code First, the database has already been built and I simply create a model to mirror it.  I am not sure of the role EF plays, though I assume it's in there somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the `<NotMapped>` attribute to the property.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  I thought I had added "Read Only" like `Public ReadOnly Property myProp as Type` but I guess that won't work here?